# Trimming string removes more than needed

Tags: java

The below code is meant to trim my string. Unfortunately it's removing more than the 'conf' value.

Did I do this correctly?

What this is doing is adding a double html response address, so i'm removing the first url which is 'conf'

```
String pageIdUrl = response.getRedirectUrl();

if(pageIdUrl.startsWith(conf.toString()));
{
    pageIdUrl = pageIdUrl.substring(conf.toString().length());
}
```

Comment: There seems to be some garbage at the end of your code snippet... ?

Comment: dump conf.toString() quoted and its length; are you sure it is not longer than you expect? (final spaces or any other non-visibile char?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would appear that there is a misplaced semicolon that is stopping your if statement from working as you expect.

```
String pageIdUrl = response.getRedirectUrl();

if(pageIdUrl.startsWith(conf.toString()))
{
    pageIdUrl = pageIdUrl.substring(conf.toString().length());
}
Console.WriteLine(conf.toString());
Console.WriteLine(pageIdUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(pageIdUrl.startsWith(conf.toString()));
                                         ^
```

Note the semicolon here. The then-action is empty: if the condition is met, nothing is done.

```
{
    pageIdUrl = pageIdUrl.substring(conf.toString().length());
}
```

This part happens whether or not the condition is met, because it's just another follow-on statement. Yes, you're allowed to use braces like that. They create an extra scope for local variable names.

What's happening is that your string doesn't actually start with the conf string, and is getting chomped anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You kept one semicolon after if statement.

```
String pageIdUrl = "conf:xxx";
        String conf = "conf";

        if (pageIdUrl.startsWith(conf.toString())){        
            pageIdUrl = pageIdUrl.substring(conf.toString().length());
            System.out.println(pageIdUrl);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the problem is with the extra ";".  Tip: If you're and Eclipse user, I'd recommend setting the Compile/Error Warnings for "Empty Statement" to Warning or Error.  Eclipse will then flag this problem in your editor.  Other IDE's may well offer something similar.